# Problem building octomap_mapping

Tags: ros, octomap, octomap-mapping, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all! i got these errors during catkin_make:

```
In file included from /home/gordon/catkin_ws/src/octomap_mapping/octomap_server/include/octomap_server/TrackingOctomapServer.h:33:0,
                 from /home/gordon/catkin_ws/src/octomap_mapping/octomap_server/src/TrackingOctomapServer.cpp:30:
/home/gordon/catkin_ws/src/octomap_mapping/octomap_server/include/octomap_server/OctomapServer.h:46:29: fatal error: pcl/conversions.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pcl/conversions.h>
                             ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/gordon/catkin_ws/src/octomap_mapping/octomap_server/include/octomap_server/OctomapServerMultilayer.h:32:0,
                 from /home/gordon/catkin_ws/src/octomap_mapping/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerMultilayer.cpp:30:
/home/gordon/catkin_ws/src/octomap_mapping/octomap_server/include/octomap_server/OctomapServer.h:46:29: fatal error: pcl/conversions.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pcl/conversions.h>
                             ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/gordon/catkin_ws/src/octomap_mapping/octomap_server/src/OctomapServer.cpp:30:0:
/home/gordon/catkin_ws/src/octomap_mapping/octomap_server/include/octomap_server/OctomapServer.h:46:29: fatal error: pcl/conversions.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pcl/conversions.h>
                             ^
compilation terminated.
```

I already checked the CMakeLists.txt with:
https://github.com/sdmiller/pcl/commit/1f3732771ff0aceaaaeff9ebbb81baf2c8fd2db8

Now I not sure where went wrong.

Thanks for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215757/problem-building-octomap_mapping/) by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys! I solved the problem.

If anybody of you encounter this problem on Groovy (I can't confirm for other version, although you can try), you **don't have to catkin_make octomap_mapping package**.

Follow the 1.1 Installation @
http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_mapping

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-octomap ros-groovy-octomap-mapping
```

Make sure your environment setup is correct as stated in tutorial.

And run

```
rosdep install octomap_mapping
rosmake octomap_mapping
```

With that, octomap and its dependencies are installed.

To navigate and run, just

```
roscd octomap_server
```

and

```
ls
```

The launch/src folders are all there.

---

Originally posted by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) with karma: 97 on 2015-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0